# Android Verilook Embedded SDK integration

Tags: android, sdk

I am an Android Mobile Application Developer. I want to integrate [Verilook Embedded SDK](http://www.neurotechnology.com/vl_sdk.html) for face detection/recognition and fingerprint detection. I need guidance how to do this.

This is link to download [SDK and Documentation PDF file](http://www.neurotechnology.com/download.html#megamatcher_verifinger_verilook_verieye_sdk_trial) and download **Biometric SDKs trials**.

Comment: were you able to do so? help me for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**Step 1 :** Download the Zip File

**Step 2 :** Unzip it

**Step 3:** Browse to unziped foler MegaMatcherEmbeddedFolder->Documentation->MegaMatcher.pdf.It says clearly what to do.

**Steps To Run Samples**(Still these steps are in the pdf)

MegaMatcher 1.1, VeriFinger 1.1, VeriLook 1.1, VeriEye 1.0 and VeriSpeak 1.0 Embedded SDK for Android Java projects (sample programs) are built and managed using Eclipse and Apache Maven tool.

Instructions for compiling Java samples using Maven:
(Note: Eclipse Indigo or later has Apache Maven integrated. If you are using Eclipse Indigo or later it is not required to perform steps 1-2).

1. Download (http://maven.apache.org/download.html) and integrate Apache Maven for Eclipse (http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html). Java projects require Apache Maven version 3.0.3 or later. Downloaded Maven package contains README.txt file with installation instructions.
2. Integrate Apache Maven to Eclipse IDE. (http://eclipse.org/m2e/).
3. Run Eclipse IDE and import Java project (one of sample application provided with SDK). Select
   File->Import->Maven->Existing Maven projects. Press Next button.
4. In the next dialog window browse for Samples root folder in SDK. Select projects pom.xml file and press Next.
5. In the last window just select Finish button.
6. In Eclipse find imported project in Package Explorer and right click on it. Select Run As -> Maven Install. It will start downloading required packages. If it will report missing dependencies (see console output) right click on the project again and choose Run As -> Maven Build. In the Main tab find Goals field and type validate.

   7.To deploy and run a project right click on it and select Run As -> Maven Build... In the Main tab find Goals field and type "android:redeploy android:run".

Hope it helps.